# Dragging and dropping mixed content

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components

I have a related list component with drop zones that handles files dropped on it from the desktop. The back end for these files is OneDrive, not Salesforce. This piece of functionality is working fine.

However, I also have a requirement for it to handle drag-n-drop from a file list. It would NOT actually be re-uploading the file as much as associating the file ID with the item ID in the related list.

So my question is: How do I differentiate between a desktop file and text or other data dragged from another lightning component?

```
handleDropEvent: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    let itemId = event.currentTarget.dataset.itemId;

    // IF a file is dropped, do this...
    let files = event.dataTransfer.files;
    // Upload files, etc.

    // Otherwise, associate the existing file ID that was dragged from the pop-out column
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inspecting dataTransfer.Types to help you distinguish.

More info found in this post,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848043/how-do-i-detect-a-file-is-being-dragged-rather-than-a-draggable-element-on-my-pa

Comment: Thanks for the link! This is something I've had a hard time finding in searches. I tested and it works. Result is either: ["Files"] or ["text/plain", "text/uri-list", "text/html"]. That gives me enough info to go on.